# Java: Substring to arrray of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I have this String:

```
Java                             2              5             22              8
```

I want an Array of Strings with these values:

```
["2"; "5"; "22"; "8"]
```

Is there a way to use subString() method in order to do so, or should I take another approach?

Comment: What's wrong with 8?

Comment: I missed that one. Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: Try using `split`?

Comment: Regexing the numerics out of the string would probably be your best bet here.

Comment: Are there always precisely 4 (space-delimited) numbers per text-string, or can that 'amount' very per string also?

Comment: There are always 4 space/delimited numbers.

Comment: Why does this have so many downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit on split and regex, I found the answer: `line.split("[ ]{2,}")`

Comment: I think you'll find `line.split("\\s+")` will work better :)

Answer (score 1):

Nevertheless how many spaces there are:

```
String str = "Java    5     22     8";

String[] arr = 
  str
  .replaceAll("( )+"," ")
  .replaceFirst("Java ", "")
  .split(" ");

for (String a : arr) {
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seen to be uninterested in `"Java"` prefix, so you can call `substring` and `trim` (to remove the spaces around the 4 numbers):

```
line.substring(4).trim() // equals "2              5             22              8"
```

You can then `split` the line by one or more whitespace characters. The Java regex to do this is `"\\s+"`, since `\\s` matches a whitespace character, and `+` means "one or more".

```
line.substring(4).trim().split("\\s+") // equals ["2", "5", "22", "8"]
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use substring, here is some, probably, non optimal solution. You start from the beginning of the string, look for first number, than continue to find next char that is not number. Do substring between, and then continue looking for next number.

```
  while (i<s.length()){
  char c=s.charAt(i);
  if(c>='0'&&c<='9'){
  j=i;
   char c1=s.charAt(j);
  while ((c1>='0'&&c1<='9')&&j<s.length()){ 
      c1=s.charAt(j);
      j++;
      }
  strings[p++]=s.substring(i, j);
   i=j;   
  }else i++;

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't tell if these are seperated by a space or not, but if so you can use the `.split()` method on your String.

Example:

```
String sampleString = "2 5 22 8";
String[] stringArray = sampleString.split(" ");
```